# Trouble deploying telegram bot on Render

Tags: python, telegram, web-hosting, python-module, telebot

I am trying to deploy this telegram bot on Render, but the deploy always fails (although on the first minutes after I receive the build successful log, it works perfectly).
However, minutes later the deploy fails and I keep getting this error log:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

Here is the "bot.py" script I coded. Suppressed some non important parts of the code. Also, all "src." modules were created by me for better code organization. There are no telebot methods used on those modules.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date
import src.visualization.visualize as vz
import src.auxiliary.auxiliary as aux
import src.data.wrangling as w
import src.data.database as db
import os

import telebot

API = os.getenv("API_KEY")
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["IBOVESPA", "SP500", "NASDAQ"])
def responder(mensagem):
    # generic code and calculations suppressed
    if condition:
    # telebot method used
        bot.send_photo(
            mensagem.chat.id,
            photo = photo
        )
        
    else:
        # more generic code suppressed
    # telebot method used
        bot.send_message(
            mensagem.chat.id,
            aux.create_answer(assets)
        )
        # telebot method used
        bot.send_photo(
            mensagem.chat.id,
            photo = photo
        )

def verificar(mensagem):
    return True

def calculating_msg(mensagem, date):
    # telebot method used
    bot.send_message(
        mensagem.chat.id, 
        “generic answer”
    )

@bot.message_handler(func=verificar)
def responder(mensagem):
    text= ( 
            “standard reply to any message”
        )
    # telebot method used
    bot.reply_to(mensagem, text)

# telebot method used
bot.polling()
```

Already revoked an old api_key on telegram and used a fresh-generated one and nothing changes.

Edit: works perfectly running on local. Only receive this warning:

```
\src\visualization\visualize.py:34: UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
```

Comment: You mean the generic code supressed? If so, no telebot method is used there, you can think as a print("Hello world") instead.
And the same about the modules "src." I imported as well, no telebot method used.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using the option "clear build cache and deploy" instead of "deploy latest commit". And also implementing error handling when starting the bot. I used [grammy](https://grammy.dev) to create the bot.

However, before I arrived at that conclusion one thing that i thought could possibly solve my problem was implementing a webhook solution instead of using long polling. But I Don't know if that would actually solve the problem.